# How do i retrieve the current URL when I am in Startup.Auth.cs

Tags: model-view-controller

I would like to get the current URL while I am in Startup.Auth.cs.
This does not work.
HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

Comment: In what function inside (Startup.Auth.cs) do you want to use it?